# Code doesn't finish executing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written the following code in order to analyse data from file. However, when I implement the code, it just hangs and doesn't complete with some derived data printed to screen. What is the problem with it, if any?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

infile=open("ratios.dat","r")
outfile=open("corr_ratios.txt","wb")
outfile2=open("corr_ratios2.txt","wb")

data=infile.readlines()

i=0
while i < len(data):
    if i+2 < len(data) and data[i+2].startswith("Model "):
        outfile.write(" ")
        outfile.write("\n")
        i=i+2;
    elif i+8 < len(data):
        targetline=data[i+8]
        outfile.write(targetline.split(" ")[0]+"\n")
        outfile2.write(targetline.split(" ")[2]+"\n")
        i=i+11;


count=0
sum=0.0
infile2=open("corr_ratios.txt","r")
data2=infile2.readlines()
for j,line in enumerate(data2):
    if data2[j]!=" ":
        count=count+1
        sum=sum+float(data[j])


mean=sum/count
print count,sum,mean
```

Comment: What happens if `i = len(data) - 2`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. The purpose of that part of the if-statement is to allow the program reach the end of the input file without any errors. Is this where the problem is?

Comment: For that specific `i`, you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: True Blender. I just realized this. I changed it to a <= in both cases (for the elif too), but now it says the list index is out of range.

Comment: I'm having more fun trying to work out what that input file must look like. In all seriousness though, I think you should work out if you can iterate over the lines, perhaps use the data list as a stack. It's hard to be more specific though without looking at the input.

Comment: Can you describe the format or content of the file `ratios.dat`? Situations where the line at `i + 2` doesn't start with `"Model "` and `i + 8 >= len(data)` will loop endlessly, but the input file format is needed to determine the best way to avoid that eventuality.

Comment: The format of the file is firstly two lines of text, followed by 9 lines of data values (two adjacent columns of nine values), and then the two lines of text again (one includes "Model") and then 9 more lines of data in the form of two columns. There are instances where the data isn't written to file, in which case the two lines of text are followed by the next two lines of text. It's ok though, I solved it by adding an else: break statement.

Answer (score 1):

My own mistake here. I accessed the "data" array instead of the "data2" array in the sum equation within the last if-statement at the bottom of the code.

Should have been:

```
for j,line in enumerate(data2):
    if data2[j]!=" ":
        count=count+1
        sum=sum+float(data2[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop must be occurring inside the while loop. `i` is initialized to 0. The while loop spins until i hits the boundary of the array. For each iteration, if `i+2` does not go out of bounds and the current line starts with "Model ", advance i by 2. Otherwise, if `i+8` will not overflow the boundary, advance `i` by 11. Thus, if neither of those conditions is true, the while loop will never terminate.

I think perhaps there needs to be an else condition in this block:

```
else:
    i += 1
```

Comment: I included an else: break condition that allowed the script to execute without errors. Hopefully with more practice, I can see where the infinite loops are occurring. Thank you for your suggestion.